# Email Link Password-Less Signin : 400 API key expired error on web browser

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

So I have email link signin (password less) working for iOS and Android, but if a user requests the email and then opens it on a web browser, they see this message:

Error encountered
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"API key expired. Please renew the API key.","errors":[{"message":"API key expired. Please renew the API key.","domain":"global","reason":"badRequest"}],"status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}

I need them to click the link using their mobile device in order for the authentication to work, but ideally I could provide a more graceful message here that tells them to open the link on the mobile device. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've now got this redirecting to my own website. Long story short - for some reason my Firebase hosting site was not configured properly and thus this authentication url was not being handled as it should. Fixable by recreating hosting site or just creating an additional site under hosting and using that for the email action url.

What I did was:

1. Create an Additional Site on Firebase Hosting. I made it additional so I wouldn't have to worry about messing with the Dynamic Link setup that is currently working on the default site.
2. Then under Authentication > Templates in the Firebase console, I changed the action url to use the new site but still have the (__/auth/action?...) path after the domain.
3. Now, when this url is accessed via a desktop browser, the user is redirected to the continue url (specified in the action code settings of the mobile app) and I display what I want on this continue url.

I noticed that in my Google API console, Firebase created a new Browser key and that it is being used whenever this auth link is clicked. Perhaps this was the issue all along. I wonder if I somehow restricted the wrong key. Anyways, if you run into a similar issue, check your API keys and their restrictions and/or just create a new additional site in Firebase hosting and use that.